# Microsoft PowerAutomate workflow for multiple approval

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image][image]i am creating a asset allocation form with approval flow. Please find my requirements below.

Approval Workflow:
1- User is able to create the item.
2- As per approval flow, Item is going for approval for the respective manager & email also triggering to user if it approve or reject.
3 - After approval it is going to the next approval. If any approve or reject happens from 2nd approver, It is not updating the sharepoint list field. It is only replacing the existing approval status and comment list.

Reject Workflow:
1- If reporting manger is rejecting the request with some commenets (Ex- number of requirement is not mentioned). It is still going to user with the approval or rejection status.But when user is modifying the existing list according to Approver comment, Emails are not triggering as well as Approval status is not updating.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I think we are going to need a lot more details about the steps in your Flow, including screenshots of your actions.  Kind of hard to tell you where the mistakes are without seeing the configuration of your steps.

Comment: How can i share you the screenshot.

Comment: Open your Flow in the Power Automate designer and use the Windows Snipping Tool or similar third-part screen capture software to either snag the entire Flow, or at least key actions.

Comment: added screenshot to the original post, Please check, Flow is able to update recruitment status field but not the recruiter comment field.

Comment: that is a screenshot of your list, which doesn't help with diagnosing much.  Please go to flow.microsoft.com to open the steps of your Flow, and take snapshots of your Flow Actions.

Comment: Hi Willman, Thanks for time, I have resolve the issue myself.

Comment: I have one more issue with regards to disable or readonly one field in edit view. Can you please help me on this.